# I wrote a simple function to reverse a linked list recursively. It returns the updated head pointer

Tags: c, algorithm, linked-list

```
struct node* reverse(struct node *head)  
{  
static struct node *prev =NULL;  
if(head==NULL) return prev;  
struct node *q = head->next;  
head->next=prev;  
prev=head;  
return reverse(q);  
}
```

I dont see any problem in it. Can anybody suggest if i am doing something wrong

Comment: Well, what happened when you tested it?

Comment: .. with just two entries in the list, to make things easier and clearer..

Comment: .. as you stepped through with your debugger, making notes of all the var values at each step.

Comment: Suppose that you had two lists and wanted to reverse both, or wanted to reverse a list twice. How about that `static` variable?

Answer (score 2):

If you try to use this function twice, then the behavior you will experience will not be the same as the one you desire, since the `static` variable is used once. Instead of that, I suggest something like this:

```
struct node* reverse(struct node *current, isHead)
{
    if (current->next == NULL)
    {
        return current;
    }
    struct node* ret = reverse(current->next);
    if (isHead)
    {
        current->next = NULL;
    }
    current->next->next = current;
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems here.  You definitely don't want to be using `static` variables for something like this.  Try the following:

```
struct node *reverse(struct node *head)
{
    if (head == NULL) return NULL;
    struct node *q = head->next;
    if (q == NULL) return head;
    struct node *r = reverse(q);
    q->next = head;
    head->next = NULL;
    return r;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the function is that you may not call it more than just one time.:) Because the static local variable `prev` is initialized only once when (before) the function was called the first time.

Comment: It would be interesting to see a comment from someone who down-voted.:)